# SSO between .NET and SharePoint 2010 (Same Domain)

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, multi-tenant, adfs

I have setup my `MVC` application already to use the `Membership` provider along with `AD`.

I am able to login and see details about users and such.

My next step is to implement some sort of `SSO` with my `SharePoint 2010` application. From what I understand, `Claims-Based` authentication may be a good approach for my situation. Both my `MVC` app and the `SharePoint` app will be hosted on the same domain if this helps with the question.

I have setup a `Claims-Based SharePoint` application, so I'm assuming I need to find out how to let `SharePoint` know that the user has logged into my `MVC` app so they don't need to login again, which is where ADFS might come into play.

Does anybody have any experience with this topic. If so, are there any resources available to look at for research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that Active Directory already supports multi-tenancy within a domain.

Make certain that `applicationName` setting in your web.config is the same for your Sharepoint and MVC apps.

```
  <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear/>
<add
  name="MyADMembershipProvider"
  type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, 
        Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
  connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
.......
                applicationName="/"
            />
        </providers>
  </membership>
```

Comment: I was under this impression as well. I'm assuming you meant to put a Active Directory membership provider?

1. Do I still need to setup the SharePoint application to use Claims
2. Do I need to add this membership provider user the STS web.config as well as the application's web.config?

Comment: yeah, that was cut and paste from wrong source. I'll look for a better fit.

Comment: Thanks! Mind answering my questions from the previous comment?

Comment: Whether or not you use claims with sharepoint should not matter. Once you have an authorized session or cookie. What's important is the authorizing source and applicationName

Comment: I see, but I need to use the same providers for both my .NEt and SharePoint applications?

Comment: "Provider" could mean a few things. The repository of user data must be the same. Otherwise I think you have can use services for one and not the other.

Comment: Sorry, I was/am trying to ask if I need to modify the SharePoint applications web.config to include the same membership provider you listed in your answer ?

Comment: I would say yes, but here I'm not certain if there are other options with claims and what affect. This may have to be a A/B test scenario. First configure identically, then play around with variances.

Comment: Still unable to get this working. Everything is identical across the board but I keep getting the login screen for sharepoint.